# Как создать триггер, который заполнял бы поле значением с другой таблицы?

Tags: mysql

Столкнулся с такой проблемой. Мне нужно реализовать триггер, который смог бы

вставлять значение с другой таблицы при вставке. То есть писав

```
insert into table(column1, column2) values (1,'hello'),(2,'world');
```

в column 3 заполнялось значением с другой таблицы при условии что column2='Первый'.
Сами по себе первая таблица связана со второй по внешнему ключу.

```
CREATE TABLE `price` (
    `nomer_flight_price` int NOT NULL,
    `1st_class_cost` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL,
    `business_class_cost` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL,
    `economy_class_cost` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`nomer_flight_price`)
);

CREATE TABLE `ticket` (
    `nomer_flight` int NOT NULL,
    `departure_date` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    `class` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
    `price` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL,
    `discounts` DECIMAL(3,1) NOT NULL,
    `taxes` DECIMAL(3,1) NOT NULL,
    `agency_fee` DECIMAL(3,1) NOT NULL,
    `baggage_allowance` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    `nomer_ticket` int NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`nomer_ticket`)
);

ALTER TABLE `ticket` ADD CONSTRAINT `ticket_fk0` FOREIGN KEY (`nomer_flight`) REFERENCES `price`(`nomer_flight_price`);
```

Триггер нужен для таблицы ticket.
Так же вот моя попытка написать данный триггер, да я там ошибся кое-где.

```
create trigger trigger_name
     before insert
     on ticket
     for each row
     begin
     if (select price.1st_class_cost from price where price.nomer_flight_price=new.nomer_flight)='Первый' THEN
     insert into ticket (price) values (price.1st_class_cost);
     elseif (select price.business_class_cost from price where price.nomer_flight_price=new.nomer_flight)='Бизнес' THEN
     insert into ticket (price) values (price.business_class_cost);
     elseif (select price.economy_class_cost from price where price.nomer_flight_price=new.nomer_flight)='Эконом' THEN
     insert into ticket (price) values (price.economy_class_cost);
     end if;
     end;
```

Comment: Вы неправильно понимаете то, как работают триггеры в MySQL. Никаких INSERT INTO ticket в триггере не должно быть даже близко. Триггер работает со вставляемой записью - именно её и надо изменять с помощью SET.

Comment: @Akina спасибо за совет. И вашему шаблону. Благодаря вам у меня все получилось и я лучше стал понимать триггеры. Единственное я добавил end case.

Comment: @Akina вы не знаете можно ли использовать and в case например case column1 and column2?

Comment: Условие в CASE - это абсолютно любое выражение, возвращающее скалярный результат, который может быть приведён к булеву значению.

Comment: @akina то есть я могу написать две строки объединеные в and?

Comment: Да хоть четыре... только следите за правильностью синтаксиса.

Answer (score 0):

Шаблон:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name
BEFORE INSERT ON ticket
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
CASE NEW.class 
    WHEN 'Первый' THEN 
        SET NEW.price = ( SELECT 1st_class_cost
                          FROM price
                          WHERE nomer_flight_price = NEW.nomer_flight );
    WHEN 'Бизнес' THEN 
        SET NEW.price = ( SELECT business_class_cost
                          FROM price
                          WHERE nomer_flight_price = NEW.nomer_flight );
    WHEN 'Эконом' THEN 
        SET NEW.price = ( SELECT economy_class_cost
                          FROM price
                          WHERE nomer_flight_price = NEW.nomer_flight );
    END;
END
```

Т.е. в зависимости от значения поля `class` во вставляемой записи выполняется присвоение вставляемому значению поля `price` цены, полученной запросом из соответствующего поля таблицы `price`. Если же поле содержит значение, не упомянутое в вариантах оператора CASE, то никакого SET не будет выполнено, и значение поля `price` во вставляемой записи не будет изменено.

По завершении работы триггера выполняется собственно вставка, причём вставка записи в том состоянии и с теми значениями полей, которые были установлены/изменены в триггере. Понятно, что если значение поля в триггере не менялось, то вставлено будет значение, предоставленное запросом.